# different beween self.null and none in red-black tree implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, red-black-tree

I don't understand a part of the code in the implementation of the red-black tree, specifically the use of  `self.null` . Could you explain what  `self.null`  represents and how it differs from `None`? Why are there instances where `None` is used in some places, but  `self.null`  is used in others? If I were to replace  `self.null`  with  `None` , what implications would that have on the functionality of the code?

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val                                   # Value of Node
        self.parent = None                               # Parent of Node
        self.left = None                                 # Left Child of Node
        self.right = None                                # Right Child of Node
        self.color = 1                                   # Red Node as new node is always inserted as Red Node

# Define R-B Tree
class RBTree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.NULL = Node ( 0 )
        self.NULL.color = 0
        self.NULL.left = None
        self.NULL.right = None
        self.root = self.NULL


    # Insert New Node
    def insertNode(self, key):
        node = Node(key)
        node.parent = None
        node.val = key
        node.left = self.NULL
        node.right = self.NULL
        node.color = 1                                   # Set root colour as Red

        y = None
        x = self.root

        while x != self.NULL :                           # Find position for new node
            y = x
            if node.val < x.val :
                x = x.left
            else :
                x = x.right
```

I tried to understand the difference between self.null and none, but I couldn't. especially in this line  x! self.null

Comment: That's not the full code for `insertNode`; it's missing the part where you actually *add* the new node in the correct position and rebalance the tree as necessary. It's possible `self.NULL` is used as a sort of pre-allocated node as part of the rebalancing?

Comment: This is just a choice made by the programmer. In the literature you also read that some define a *leaf* as a NULL node with a black color, which maybe inspired the coder to define it as a `Node` instance. In the code you have shared there is no apparent advantage to doing it this way, but you only showed 10% of the whole red-black tree implementation, and it might well be that other code can benefit from this approach. For instance, it will not lead to an error when accessing the `val` attribute of such a null node, while doing that with a `None` value would give an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Self.NULL` is called a "[sentinel node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node)".  It's an actual `Node` object that is used in place of a `None` or `null` value at all the places in the tree where nodes are missing.

This is commonly used in red-black trees to simplify the code.  The code is simpler, because you can check the color of a sentinel node (nulls are black) without testing first to see if the node exists.  This removes a lot if `if node == None` checks that would otherwise be required.